# Eclipse Market place - UML designer - installation error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-marketplace, uml-designer

Getting below error while I try to install UML Designer plugin from eclipse market place.

Unable to read repository at https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/obeo-networkaggregation-releases/sirius_5_1/content.xml.
Unable to make member of class sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl accessible:  module java.base does not export sun.security.ssl to unnamed module @6e454ac

Is it Bad link in marketplace, or java installation of my machine?

Comment: It seems to be a bad link in the Marketplace. Does the following update site URL work: `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/obeo-networkaggregation-releases/5.1.0/`?

Comment: above error was due to java 9, I switched to java 8(Thx for someone who hinted this in comment, now comment is removed, not sure about reason).  Error message changed, and it clearly states now that UML 8.1 is not available to download(bad-link in market place).

Comment: @howlger , not able to figureout how to install plugin using above link.

Comment: In _Help > Install New Software..._ enter the URL in the field _Work with_.

Comment: @howlger , thx, it worked.

Comment: one more issue i faced was UML 8.1 has dependency on plugin https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sirius,  which needs to install this plugin first

Comment: @GururajaHegde The mention of _module_ in the error message suggests that you're using Java 9 (as the concept of modules was introduced in Java 9). It seems that UML designer is not yet fully compatible with Java 9. Using Java 8 will do the trick (as you already stated in your comment above; I'm adding this comment because I accidentally fat-fingered on mobile, deleting my previous comment... glad to see it helped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bad link in the Marketplace. Do the following instead:

1. Open ***Help > Install New Software...***
2. In the field ***Work with*** enter **`https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/obeo-networkaggregation-releases/5.1.0/`** and click ***Enter***
3. Choose the UML Designer and install it